# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'productinquiry' already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have uploaded one of my projects in the server which is in magento 1.9. I have changed the base_url all details in the database. But there is an error, the error is shown below :

> Exception during cache and session cleaning: Error in file: "/home/pxxxs/public_html/app/code/community/SorenInfotech/ProductInquiry/sql/productinquiry_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'productinquiry' already exists

Can anyone know how to solve this ? Module "ProductInquiry" show in admin panel but cant show on product page.

Answer (score 0):

check in database that there is a table that name is 'productinquiry'

and if table exist with no data

then delete that table

and clear `var/cache` , `var/session` and reload page

Comment: Already done but issue is not resolved.